# Changing content of numerous span tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope to you'll be able to solve my problem, spent the last 3 hours trying to solve it.

First of all, I have about a thousand span tag containing numbers or a dot.
It's working as a header for a library, numbers represents the id of a column, only even numbers are shown, odd numbers are remplaced by a dot in order to avoid numbers overlapping.
Sadly I can use anything other than span tag as the library works this way.

```
<div class="marker" style="font-size: 10px;">
     <span>
       <span class="header" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block;">.</span>
       <span class="header" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block;">2</span>
       <span class="header" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block;">.</span>
       <span class="header" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block;">4</span>
       .                                                                    .
       .                                                                    .
       .                                                                    .
       <span class="header" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block;">936</span>
       <span class="header" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block;">.</span>
       <span class="header" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block;">938</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

My goal is to change the numbers (ie column id). For this purpose, I have an 2-dimensional array, containing the number I want to change (left) and the new number (right). For example :

```
var arrayCorres = [[448, 603], ... ,[345, 666] ]
```

In this example, the column id 448 will be changed in column id 603, same for 345 to 666.
A column id that doesn't exist in `arrayCorres` will be changed to a blank column id.

So I made the following function to search in the array for the new value of a column id :

```
function changeId(array,value){
    for (ite = 0; ite < array.length; ite++){
        if (value == array[ite][0]){
            return(array[ite][1]);
        }
    }
}
```

This function returns the new column id, or `undefined` if the column id isn't in the array, meaning it has to be changed to a blank column id.

Now I use this function to update a single span tag by giving its id in the parameters :

```
function newSpanId(array,id){
    var tmp = changeId(array,id);
    if (tmp!=undefined){
       $(".marker").find('span')[id].innerText=tmp; 
    }
    else {
        $(".marker").find('span')[id].innerText="";
    }
}
```

Now, as you may have guessed, I'll like to update all of the spans tag id.

I use the following function :

```
function updateSpans(array){
    var max = ($(".marker").find('span').length );
    for (ite = 1; ite < max; ite++){
        newSpanId(array,ite);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that `newSpanId(array,id)` works well, it changes the span id to a new one according to the array given in parameters but when I use `updateSpans(array)`, I get an error in firebug of "Unresponsive Script" :

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding.
>   You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let
>   the script continue.

How to make all the span tags to update ?
Thanks for your time !

Comment: try calling newSpanValue(array,ite) like this setTimeout(function(){ newSpanValue(array,ite); }, 0); inside updateSpans function.

Comment: @FahadNisar I get a new error : "TypeError: $(...).find(...)[value] is undefined"

Comment: can you paste newSpanValue() function as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.each()` to iterate array, `filter()`  to match `.header` element where `.textContent` is equal to number at first index of current array, `.text()` to set new text content

```js
var arrayCorres = [
  [448, 603],
  [345, 666]
];

$.each(arrayCorres, function(index, arr) {
  $(".header").filter(function(index, el) {
      return el.textContent == arr[0]
    })
    .text(arr[1])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="marker" style="font-size: 10px;">
  <span>
       <span class="header" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block;">.</span>
  <span class="header" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block;">448</span>
  <span class="header" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block;">.</span>
  <span class="header" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block;">345</span>
  <span class="header" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block;">936</span>
  <span class="header" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block;">.</span>
  <span class="header" style="width: 15px; display: inline-block;">938</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1cjxh5o2/

Comment: It didn't change any of the column ids, only printed arrayCorres in the console.

Comment: What do you mean by "column ids"? No element at `HTML` at Question has an `id` set

Comment: I meant any of the text content was not changed. Sorry to have been misleading, but the text content I'm trying to change is, in fact, used as column id for a library.

Comment: @AurélienPaillarse See updated post. Was missing `index` parameter at `$.each()` and `.filter()`, or rather was using `index` parameter as value parameter

Comment: It changed the text content that existed in arrayCorres, thank you ! Do you have an idea to change the text content that doesn't exist in arrayCorres to " " ?

Comment: @AurélienPaillarse Do you mean  elements with `"."` set as text content, or any `.header` element that does not have text content matching a value in array?

Comment: I found a way ! Thanks for your help